# Set Maya Display Layers to Off with PythonScript

Tags: python, performance, maya

This should work but it does not....do I need to replace the variables or something?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def setLayerTo(attrib, value, selected=False):
    layers = cmds.ls(long=True, type='displayLayer')
    for l in layers[1:]:
        selectionStatus = cmds.layerButton(l, query=True, select=True)
        if(not selected or selectionStatus): 
            cmds.setAttr( '%s.%s' % (l, attrib), value)

setLayerTo('visibility', value=0, selected=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, the following method would let you toggle the visibility of a named display layer:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

def toggleLayer(name, on):
    '''Toggle display layer visibility

    Args:
        name (str): Display layer name
        on (bool): True to enable layer, False to disable
    '''

    cmds.setAttr('{}.visibility'.format(name), on)
    cmds.layerButton(name, edit=True, layerVisible=on)
    

# Example usage
toggleLayer('OrangePeel', False)
```

Unlike the method from the original post, this is specifically designed for display layer buttons and their associated display layer.

Edit: Actually, my fault for poor reading, the original method is also specifically dealing with display layer -- just neglects to mark the buttons' check-state.

Comment: Much appreciated, you've set me off in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it works, it only does not update the visibility button of the layerUI. You can check it if you put a geomtry into the layer and apply your script. In my scene the object disappears if the script is applied.

I have no idea how an ui update can be done.

Comment: If you trace the Maya commands that occur on a layer visibility change, you get pointed to `setDisplayLayerVisibility()` in `layerEditor.mel`. More specifically to this MEL command: `layerButton -edit -layerVisible 0|1 <layer name>;`

`cmds.layerButton()` is the Python equivalent.

Comment: Nice, yes that's what I needed, is there any way you could put this line into a real line of Python code? The Layers name is: 'OrangePeel'....thanks this is a first script by me where I am just trying to implement the 'DragAttrContext' command to actually use the mmouse button to move drag visibilities on or off of the displaylayers in Maya....

Comment: cmds.layerButton(name='OrangePeel', edit=True, layerVisible[0:1]; cmds.layerButton()  this is as close as I'm getting right now...very very new to Python...